# How to Change Preempitibility of a Google Cloud Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to activate the Preempitibility Mode on an active Google Cloud VM? It doesn't change either through command line or the via console even it is stopped.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can read this guide: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible. It describes how to create preemptible vms

Comment: Not aware of any option to convert from on-demand to PVM or vice-versa dynamically, but you could of course capture an image from the on-demand instance and then launch a new PVM instance from that.